# Installing Ubuntu on an SSD from a HDD on same box

Tags: system-installation

I bought a Dell with Windows installed on the SSD. The box also has an HDD. I installed Ubuntu and confirmed overwriting the current data. Ubuntu was installed but I didn't realize it installed on the HDD instead of the SSD. I spent a couple hours installing the Nvidia drivers and other libraries.

Is there a way for me to backup my current configuration, install Ubuntu on the SSD and restore the config on the HDD data on the SSD?

I looked at the disk utility and the only the HDD drive is present.

Comment: Have you updated Dell UEFI and SSD firmware. Have you added AHCI driver to Windows and changed drives from RAID or Intel SRT to AHCI? You should just be able to do a new install in UEFI mode to SSD. Only use Windows to shrink the NTFS partition and immediately reboot and run chkdsk. Then boot Ubuntu installer in UEFI mode and install to unallocated space. You can then copy /home from HDD to SSD, if room. Or use HDD as data partition. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043842/running-ubuntu-via-live-usb-error-on-dell-xps-15-9560 &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to install fresh Ubuntu to SSD and then copy all of the data from old Ubuntu installation on HDD. Use `rsync` utility to copy system files from old to new installation. See my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052563/move-ubuntu-from-one-drive-with-dual-boot-to-a-new-drive-with-single-boot/1052582#1052582).