# How to copy files from broken system onto flash drive?

Tags: kubuntu, 18.04, live-usb, backup, boot-repair

My installation broke, so I am booting up from a startup disk and copying over my files. This works for most files but for some it's saying that I don't have permission to open it, let alone copy it. I am running Ubuntu 18 on both. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  If you're using `cp` to copy files (you gave us little details on how you were trying to copy, the error message you got etc), you can elevate your permissions with `sudo cp`.  Likewise if using `scp` to [secure] copy to another [remote] machine, raise permissions with `sudo scp`

Comment: @guiverc I've tried sudo with cp, move, and I tried just copying the files over to OneDrive using nautilus. Nothing worked, either I get a "you don't have permission to do this" error, or OneDrive just hangs

Comment: @Wiking thank you! That's a cool thing that I haven't heard of yet, unfortunately I'm reinstalling Ubuntu because I want a clean install, and I just need these few files

Comment: I would suggest editing your question, adding the command you tried (eg. a `sudo cp /media/....` to your question but include the error message you get so we can provide you with help. I used `cp` as my example as it's the command I'd have used to copy a file in your situation (`scp` being my second choice if I was using a network share to store it instead of local usb-thumb-drive)..   If you get issues with `nautilus`, you could also `sudo nautilus` (ie. from terminal elevating your run of nautilus & try from there), however gui in my experience provides less helpful error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy any files and directories using `rsync` utility. To preserve all of the files access rights format your external drive to `ext4` filesystem. Next install rsync:

```
sudo apt install rsync
```

Next copy `/source_dir/` to a `/media/user/backup_dir/` on external drive:

```
sudo rsync -xrlptgoEvv --progress /source_dir/ /media/user/backup_dir/
```

Pay your attention to directory path trailing slash.

The `rsync` utility allows even to clone Ubuntu installation to a computer with different hardware - [read this my answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052563/move-ubuntu-from-one-drive-with-dual-boot-to-a-new-drive-with-single-boot/1052582#1052582).